# Loading index package with memoir

Tags: memoir, indexing, unicode, incompatibility

The standard `makeidx` package writes `ind`/`idx` in LaTeX's internal representation file.
The `index` package writes in utf-8 and works fine with the `book`, `article`, `report` standard classes. But when trying to use the `index` package with `memoir`, the output is still like with the `makeidx` package. Can the `makeidx` emulation can be turned off or overridden with the `index` package with `memoir`?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{index}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\section{Indexing something}
\index{здравствуйте}здравствуйте
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The `idx` file content is

```
\indexentry{\IeC {\cyrz }\IeC {\cyrd }\IeC {\cyrr }\IeC {\cyra }\IeC {\cyrv }\IeC {\cyrs  }
\IeC {\cyrt }\IeC {\cyrv }\IeC {\cyru }\IeC {\cyrishrt }\IeC {\cyrt }\IeC {\cyre }}{1}
```

Now change `memoir` to `book` and rebuild index and document again. Now the `idx` file content is

```
\indexentry {здравствуйте}{1}
```

as expected.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, `memoir` will prevent any packages (including `index`) from being loaded if their functionality is emulated by the class. To override this, one must add `\DisemulatePackage{index}` before `\usepackage{index}`. The following MWE produces the "expected" `.idx` file content. (`\renewindex` is used to correct the index name.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\DisemulatePackage{index}
\usepackage{index}
\makeindex
\renewindex{default}{idx}{ind}{Предметный указатель}
\begin{document}
\section{Indexing something}
\index{здравствуйте}здравствуйте
\printindex
\end{document}
```